# Событие ресайза для div?

Tags: javascript, css

Чистый JavaScript. Для `<div>` устанавливаю в CSS   `resize: both;` Всё работает. Но!
Надо отловить событие на окончание этого ресайза. Как?
Пока обхожусь событием `mouseup`, но если ли не делать ресайза, то оно тоже  отрабатывает, а этого не надо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-of-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac Посмотрите на этот вопрос

Comment: @Klimenkomud - это не то , совсем не то. нужен чистый javascript, не window

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм такой:

1. Отлавливаем `mousedown` на `div`, замеряем текущие размеры;
2. Отлавливаем `mouseup` и, если размеры изменились, то это событие и есть искомое.

Как вариант:

```js
function watch(element) {
  var w = element.clientWidth;
  var h = element.clientHeight;
  element.innerHTML = '';
  element.addEventListener('mouseup', check);

  function check() {
    if (w === element.clientWidth && h === element.clientHeight) return;
    element.removeEventListener('mouseup', check);
    element.innerHTML = 'resized';
    // add your code here
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div onmousedown="watch(this)"></div>
```

Comment: слишком замудрено, тогда уж достаточно сделать проверку на mouseup.

Comment: "но если ли не делать ресайза - то оно тоже отрабатывает . а этого не надо."

Comment: @Sam, и что? Твой ответ эту проблему не решает.

Comment: @Qwertiy Дополнил ответ.

Comment: А какие преимущества по сравнению с одним обработчиком `mouseup`, в котором так же будет проверяться размер элемента?

Comment: Кстати, не работает, если я увожу мышь за пределы окна: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM8Ol.gif

Comment: @Qwertiy Если использовать только один обработчик `mouseup`, то как ты узнаешь, что был ресайз?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71392/discussion-between-sam-and-qwertiy).